# How to install python syntax support for Vim on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, vim

I recently started programming in python and have fallen in love with Vim over the past few weeks. I know want to use Vim as my primary editor for python files. I know there are python plugins for Vim, but I am very confused as to where/how I can install these. I don't really understand where Vim is installed. I'm running the latest version of Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: even better than vim use http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/ IMNHO ;)

Comment: @hhafez... if you are going to amusingly compare anything to vim, at least make it the common argument if favor of emacs. :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting an general purpose editor to replace Vim, just something specificly for python

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To best answer your initial question: "How to install python syntax support in Vim":

There is no need to install anything! If you have not made any modifications (e.g. no configuration changes for vim in `~/.vimrc`) try the following:

- Open a Python file with vim
- type the following command `:syntax on`

You should now have VIM properly highlight your Python file.

To avoid having to re-type those command over and over again, I would suggest you keep a configuration file for VIM. This is usually located in your home directory, if there is not one there already, create a `~/.vimrc` file and add the `syntax on` directive there to 
have VIM automatically highlight your Python files.

If you need to know more about structure/installation of plugins, then Senthil's answer is better suited :)

Answer (score 10):

You will find that you have a folder by name `.vim` in your home directory `cd ~` and it will contain the following directories

```
ftdetect/  ftplugin/  plugin/  syntax/
```

You need to download the [plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) and install them (copy them) to those directories.

Apart from that, in your .vimrc file have the following lines which will enable you to write python programs following PEP8.

```
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
filetype indent on
```

There are some [good documentation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

for mac os x, the vimrc file is located in /usr/share/vim directory
edit the vimdc file with any text editor. Add the *syntax on* to the last line of the file. Then next time you start a file you can see color. This is a system wide setting.  In other linux flavor it may be located in /etc/ you can find this file by find /etc -name vimdc.  The edit will affect all the users on the machine.
These setting can overwritten by the $HOME/.vimrc file.  In your home you may also have a .vim directory.  To check that you have these, do ls -a in your home directory.